# How to add new menu Item in apache superset

Tags: python-3.x, typescript, google-cloud-platform, apache-superset

In Apache superset I want to add a new external link  in main menu .

I installed Superset in GCP . I not found superset-front [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIcBW.png) folder in GCP account.

I can access -  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/superset/static/assets     folder . but did not found front page HTML file or  typescript files

Menu.tsx file is present in  superset-frontend\src\feature\home . but where it is located in Google cloud panel.

I installed superset on  GCP . and I download it from repository .  may be both have different folder structure.